# How to set for loop on multiple survey questions in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation

I have a survey data the for loop works when the question `cmb.df$b3002` has multiple choices `1,2,3, and 4` and I can loop over each choices by `table(cmb.df$b3002)[i]` ,
but one of the questions' multiple choices were recorded as `cmb.df$b3002a_1_1_mc`, `cmb.df$b3002a_1_2_mc`,... `cmb.df$b3002a_1_9_mc`. How can I create a for loop on this? Many thanks in advance.

```
 usq <- NULL
for(i in 1:4) {
  # i-th element of `u1` squared into `i`-th position of `usq`
  usq[i] <- table(cmb.df$b3002)[i]
}

usq
[1] 5894  472  180   43
```

[image]

the dataset is huge and

```
 a <- cbind(cmb.df$b3002, cmb.df$b3002a_1_1_mc, cmb.df$b3002a_1_2_mc, cmb.df$b3002a_1_3_mc, cmb.df$b3002a_1_4_mc,
           cmb.df$b3002a_1_5_mc, cmb.df$b3002a_1_6_mc, cmb.df$b3002a_1_7_mc, cmb.df$b3002a_1_8_mc, cmb.df$b3002a_1_9_mc )


   dput(head(a, 20))
structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), .Dim = c(20L, 
10L))
```

Comment: `cmb.df$b3002a_1_1_mc`, `cmb.df$b3002a_1_2_mc`, etc, are different vectors? Note that you don't need the loop in the question, it is equivalent to `usq<-table(cmb.df$b3002_1)`.

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(cmb.df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(cmb.df, 20))`.

Comment: the main question in cmb.df$b3002a and has 9 multiple choices that each multiple-choices were recorded as cmb.df$b3002a_1_1_mc,.... cmb.df$b3002a_1_9_mc, I would like to set for loop like above but I am not sure how to save the for loop responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following `tidyverse` solution can do what the question asks for. It creates a column `"b300a"` by reshaping from wide to long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cmb.df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("b3002a"), names_to = "b3002a") %>%
  mutate(b3002a = sub("^.*(\\d+)_mc", "\\1", b3002a),
         b3002a = as.integer(b3002a)*value) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  na.omit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time but it gives Error: Can't combine `b3002a_1` <character> and `b3002a_1_1_mc` <double>. Is there any way to enter name  cmb.df$b3002a_1_[i]_mc.

Comment: @SeymaKalay Try `starts_with("b3002a_1_")` and see if it works.